# Classes not applying TailwindCSS styles in PHP File

Tags: php, html, tailwind-css

The TailwindCSS stylesheet is being properly detected by the page code, but despite this the class names are not applying the styles. I've copied this into the TailwindCSS Playground to see if it works there, and it does, so I don't know why it isn't working here.

Page Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Exceptional Kids | Login</title>
        <link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex justify-center items-center h-screen">
            <div class="border-4 border-black rounded-3xl flex justify-around p-10">
                <div class="text-center border-r-2">
                    <p class="text-xl font-bold">Login</p>
                    <form action="/api/login" method="post" class="px-5">
                        <div>
                            <label for="email">Email: </label>
                            <input type="email" name='email' class="shadow-md mx-4 my-2" /><br />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="password">Password: </label>
                            <input type="password" name='password' class="shadow-md mx-4 my-2" /><br />
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value='Login' class="border-2 p-1 my-5 rounded-md" />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center border-l-2">
                    <p class="text-xl font-bold">Sign Up</p>
                    <form action="/api/signup" method="post" class="px-5">
                        <div>
                            <label for="firstName">Enter name of parent/guardian: </label>
                            <input type="text" name='firstName' class="shadow-md mx-4 my-2" /><br />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="lastName">Enter name of parent/guardian: </label>
                            <input type="text" name='lastName' class="shadow-md mx-4 my-2" /><br />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="email">Enter parent/guardian&apos;s email: </label>
                            <input type="email" name='email' class="shadow-md mx-4 my-2" /><br />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="password">Enter password: </label>
                            <input type="password" name='password' class="shadow-md mx-4 my-2" /><br />
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value='Create Account' class="border-2 p-1 my-5 rounded-md" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

TailwindCSS Config File:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,php}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it in incognito? You might need to break the cache, such as by adding a dynamically generated querystring to `<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet">` such as `<link href="../style.css?<?= time() ?>" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem did the following:

replace this =>  
with this =>

You just need to put "?" after style.css i.e style.css?

Hope this works for you !

Answer (score -1):

first run

> npm run watch

then refresh page